# key stretching VS key stengthening

Tags: security

To quote from [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) wiki article -

> An alternative approach, called key strengthening, extends the key
>   with a random salt, but then (unlike in key stretching) securely
>   deletes the salt. This forces both the attacker and legitimate users
>   to perform a brute-force search for the salt value.

I am comfortable with what key stretching does, But I am confused on how key strengthening is achieved. How the key can be validated again if the salt is deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using a salt that's short enough that it's feasible to try all of the possibilities until you find one that decrypts the message when combined with the known key. Hence "a brute-force search for the salt value".

Answer (score 5):

The paper on the key strengthening scheme cited in the wiki article is available [here](http://scholar.googleusercontent.com/scholar?q=cache:YwWbAMfOGfYJ:scholar.google.com/&hl=en&as_sdt=0,11).

It seems they're breaking a larger salt up into two smaller salts, a public salt, which is no different than normal salting, and a private salt, which is discarded in order to make password verifications slower. The idea is that all password verifications will be slower because the private salt must always be brute-forced but this will be negligible when the correct password is provided. However, the added processing will slow down brute forcing of the password.

Comment: Is it possible for you to give the name of the paper? Link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Like all other answers said, brute-forcing is needed in every validation of password. However unlike those done by hackers which are guessing the whole password from scratch, the authentic user can provide the password which acts as a very good foundation for the brute-force search of the remaining part (which is the deleted salt), and hence speeding up the search and hold the validation time under control.

So the key is: Given the authentic user knows the password, it is easy to calculate a matching hash by brute-force.

Side note: like @pizen said in the above answer, we still need a public salt, instead of deleting **all the salts**. Otherwise it is just defeating the purpose of salting.